# Trying to create a c++ PUT request with curl with a certain body

Tags: c++, json, curl, httprequest, put

What I'm trying to recreate is this curl request.

```
curl -X PUT --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic securePasswordHash' -d '{"IconID": 54}' 'https://127.0.0.1:1233/api/v1/current/icon'
```

This command does work.

I'm trying to translate that into C++ code. So far, my code looks like this:

```cpp
  std::string wHeader = ("Authorization: Basic " + wLCUEncoded);
    std::string strJson = "{\"IconID\" : 54}"; 
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Accept: application/json");
    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, wHeader.c_str());
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, wUrl.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, strJson);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    }
```

The result looks like this:

```
{"errorCode":"BAD_REQUEST","httpStatus":400,"message":"Unknown argument '{\"IconID\" : 54}' for 'Icon'."}* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

Any tips on what I should do? I tried to convert the `strJson` into an actual json object, but that gave a funky string error:

```
{"errorCode":"BAD_REQUEST","httpStatus":400,"message":"Unknown argument '\u0002╠╠╠╠╠╠╠\u0010^J\u000Fe\u0001' for 'Icon'."}* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

Comment: Check the server logs, the two requests will probably differ in some way.

Comment: I don't have access to those logs sadly enough, I could probably send it to my own web server and see how it look, Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, strJson);` might be the culprit. Passing a `std::string` by value to this function probably won't work. Add a `.c_str()`. In addition, consider finding a proper C++ library or library wrapper.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply, What would be a proper wrapper or library?

Comment: I don't know. I've only used cURL on the commandline and from inside PHP, not from C++. Shouldn't be too complicated to find something online (https://duckduckgo.com/?q=C%2B%2B+HTTP+client+library&t=canonical&ia=web), but I'll leave the task of picking a good one to you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to include headers.

```
headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Accept: application/json");
headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Content-Type: application/json");
headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "charset: utf-8");
```